# Trying to Display a sample JSON response in Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, json, wrapper-class

What am i doing wrong? 
I have taken the json response I got from the webservice callout and trying to display the response in Visalforce page. However the button 'Submit' is not making its way to the method of the class.

**JSON response**

```
{
    "sourceOneDealerID": "XL1HX",
    "dealerName": "Townsend Auto Dealer",
    "reportingPeriod": "2019-05-01",
    "financeSourceIntegrationTypeCode": "FIFS",
    "idlPlus": "Y",
    "creditApplicationSourceCode": "SRCONE",
    "submissionCount": 15
  },
  {
    "sourceOneDealerID": "XL1HX",
    "dealerName": "Townsend Auto Dealer",
    "reportingPeriod": "2019-05-02",
    "financeSourceIntegrationTypeCode": "FIFS",
    "idlPlus": "Y",
    "creditApplicationSourceCode": "SRCONE",
    "submissionCount": 14
  }
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="Authenticator">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="JSON Deserialize JSON Response"> 
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="submit" action="{!connectCASWebService}" reRender="dealerBlock"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="dealerBlock" columns="1">
                <apex:repeat value="{!wrapper.dealerList}" var="dealer">
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                        <apex:facet name="header">Dealer {!dealer.sourceOneDealerId}</apex:facet>
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                            <apex:outputLabel value="Total Submissions" for="submissionCount;" />
                            <apex:outputText value="{!dealer.submissionTotal}" id="submissionTotal" />
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >                            
                            <apex:outputLabel value="Month To Date" for="mtd" />
                            <apex:outputText value="{!dealer.mtd }" id="mtd" />
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                        <apex:facet name="header">Dealer {!dealer.sourceOneDealerId} submissions</apex:facet>
                        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!dealer.lineItemsPerDay}" var="item" id="lineItems">
                            <apex:column value="{!item.reportingPeriod}" headerValue="Reporting Period" />
                            <apex:column value="{!item.creditApplicationSourceCode}" headerValue="Credit Application Source Code" />
                            <apex:column value="{!item.financeSourceIntegrationTypeCode}" headerValue="Finance Source Integration Type Code" />
                            <apex:column value="{!item.idlPlus}" headerValue="IDl Plus(Yes/No)?" />
                            <apex:column value="{!item.submissionCount}" headerValue="Submission Count" />
                        </apex:pageBlockTable>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>                                                                                     
        </apex:pageBlock> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
Global class Authenticator {

    public CASReport wrapper {get;set;}

    public void connectCASWebService(){

    string jsonresponse = '{ "sourceOneDealerID": "XL1HX","dealerName": "Townsend Auto Dealer", "reportingPeriod": "2019-05-01", "financeSourceIntegrationTypeCode": "FIFS", "idlPlus": "Y", "creditApplicationSourceCode": "RTEONE",  "submissionCount": 15},{"sourceOneDealerID": "XL1HX","dealerName": "Townsend Auto Dealer",  "reportingPeriod": "2019-05-02",  "financeSourceIntegrationTypeCode": "FIFS","idlPlus": "Y", "creditApplicationSourceCode": "RTEONE","submissionCount": 14} ';

      // pulling the data from the endpoint and using JSON deserialization to push it into our data structure.
        wrapper = (CASReport)JSON.deserialize(jsonresponse,CASReport.class);    
    }


}
```

---

```
public class CASReport {


    public class SubmissionsPerDay {

        public String reportingPeriod{get;set;}
        public Integer submissionCount{get;set;}
        public String idlPlus{get;set;}
        public String creditApplicationSourceCode{get;set;}
        public String financeSourceIntegrationTypeCode{get;set;}


    }

        public class Dealer {

            public string DealerName {get; set;}
            public String sourceOneDealerId {get;set;}
            public DateTime mtd {get; set;}
            public List<SubmissionsPerDay> lineItemsPerDay {get; set;}

             public integer getsubmissionTotal() {
                integer submissionCount = 29;
                // return totalcountofsubmissionsperday
                return submissionCount;
            }

    }

    public List<Dealer> dealerList {get; set;}

}
```

**DEBUG LOGS**

```
16:16:07.0 (139642)|EXECUTION_STARTED
16:16:07.0 (146279)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|0665C00000119io|VF: /apex/CASReportDisplay
16:16:07.0 (300596)|VF_DESERIALIZE_VIEWSTATE_BEGIN|0665C00000119io
16:16:07.0 (6235955)|VF_DESERIALIZE_VIEWSTATE_END
16:16:07.0 (6749210)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
16:16:07.0 (10761355)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
16:16:07.0 (12088529)|VF_SERIALIZE_VIEWSTATE_BEGIN|0665C00000119io
16:16:07.0 (29462516)|VF_SERIALIZE_VIEWSTATE_END
16:16:07.0 (31959113)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Generate Metadata
16:16:07.0 (32799460)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Generate Metadata
16:16:07.35 (35686156)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
16:16:07.35 (35686156)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

16:16:07.35 (35686156)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

16:16:07.0 (35725219)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|VF: /apex/CASReportDisplay
16:16:07.0 (36982039)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

Comment: First of all... are you *sure* that's the "JSON" data you're getting? Because it's not valid JSON. I'd expect an exception to be thrown. You have *two* objects stuck together with just a comma, and it's not wrapped in an array syntax, so it is invalid.

Comment: Apply `System.debug()`  statements in the `connectCASWebService()` method and try to debug again.

Comment: @sfdcfox , thanks for responding. This is a sample json response sent to me, and i am told that is the response I will get when i make webservice callout to the external system from salesforce.

Comment: @AjinkyaPhadnis I do have debug statement in my method. As you can see from the Debug Logs, the method id not called from VFP.